# Unknown cause of syntax error for DELETE in MariaDB 10.1

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

The code below [on db Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=129ad94e0b9ff40be60234be653762c3), when run on MariaDB 10.1 gives:

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DELETE pm  FROM   wp_postmeta pm  WHERE  post_id IN (SELECT
>   post_id 
>           ' at line 26

Query:

```
-- Block 1: Deleting all duplicate products in wp_posts table 
DELETE FROM wp_posts 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT id 
              FROM   (SELECT id, 
                             post_title, 
                             post_type, 
                             meta_value 
                      FROM   (SELECT wp_posts.id, 
                                     wp_postmeta.post_id, 
                                     post_title, 
                                     post_type, 
                                     meta_value, 
                                     Row_number() 
                                       OVER( 
                                         partition BY post_title 
                                         ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value) rn 
                              FROM   wp_postmeta 
                                     JOIN wp_posts 
                                       ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
                              WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
                                     AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
                             ) t 
                      WHERE  t.rn <> 1) AS aliasx); 

-- Block 2: Deleting all corresponding wp_postmeta.post_ids that don't have a match in wp_posts.id after the duplicate deletion above
DELETE pm 
FROM   wp_postmeta pm 
WHERE  post_id IN (SELECT post_id 
                   FROM  (SELECT post_id 
                          FROM   wp_postmeta pm 
                                 LEFT JOIN wp_posts p 
                                        ON p.id = pm.post_id 
                          WHERE  p.id IS NULL 
                                 AND p.post_type = "product") i)
```

How do I correct this error?  I note that the first and second blocks of code don't give the error when entered alone, but when entered together this error arises...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MySQL API used by WordPress does not allow you to provide two concatenated queries (in your case two DELETEs) as one. Nor does dbfiddle.  Run the queries separately.

This can be confusing if you're used to other table servers.

Answer (score 2):

It actually works just split `Delete` statements

> ```
> create table wp_posts (
>   ID integer primary key auto_increment,
>   post_title varchar(30),
>   post_type varchar(30)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> create table wp_postmeta (
>   ID integer primary key auto_increment,
>   post_id integer,
>   meta_key varchar(30) not null default '_regular_price',
>   meta_value integer not null
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into wp_posts (post_title, post_type) values
> ('Apple Pie','Product'),
> ('French Toast','Product'),
> ('Shepards Pie','Product'),
> ('Jam Pie','Product'),
> ('Jam Pie','Product'),
> ('Plate','Not a Product'),
> ('Bucket','Not a Product'),
> ('Chequebook','Not a Product'),
> ('French Toast','Product'),
> ('French Toast','Product'),
> ('Banana','Product'),
> ('Banana','Product'),
> ('Banana','Product');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_value) values
> (1,10),
> (2,5),
> (3,9),
> (4,8),
> (5,11),
> (6,12),
> (7,10),
> (8,6),
> (9,1),
> (10,1),
> (11,7),
> (12,2),
> (13,2);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> -- Deleting all duplicate products in wp_posts table 
> DELETE FROM wp_posts 
> WHERE  id IN (SELECT id 
>               FROM   (SELECT id, 
>                              post_title, 
>                              post_type, 
>                              meta_value 
>                       FROM   (SELECT wp_posts.id, 
>                                      wp_postmeta.post_id, 
>                                      post_title, 
>                                      post_type, 
>                                      meta_value, 
>                                      Row_number() 
>                                        OVER( 
>                                          partition BY post_title 
>                                          ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value) rn 
>                               FROM   wp_postmeta 
>                                      JOIN wp_posts 
>                                        ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
>                               WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
>                                      AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
>                              ) t 
>                       WHERE  t.rn <> 1) AS aliasx);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> -- Deleting all corresponding wp_postmeta.post_ids that don't have a match in wp_posts.id after the duplicate deletion above
> DELETE pm 
> FROM   wp_postmeta pm 
> WHERE  post_id IN (SELECT post_id 
>                    FROM  (SELECT post_id 
>                           FROM   wp_postmeta pm 
>                                  LEFT JOIN wp_posts p 
>                                         ON p.id = pm.post_id 
>                           WHERE  p.id IS NULL 
>                                  AND p.post_type = "product") i)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5c00c50c01c2adc354a03866109b104f)*

Comment: Haven't I already separated the queries by the use of an intervening semi colon?

Comment: that is just a SQL Editor. `;` is enough for mysql  itself but not for dbfiddle :)